pydirectinput entering incorrect key
Given the below code I am expecting the keyboard to press the page down key.  However, instead it is pressing the number 3.  All other keys I have used appear to be working correctly.  How do I get this mapped correctly?
import time
import pydirectinput

time.sleep(2)
pydirectinput.keyDown('pagedown')
time.sleep(0.01)
pydirectinput.keyUp('pagedown')


You want the sequence of keystrokes to include NumLock.
